# how to handle multiple return types in groovy Mehods?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a need to have a method to return Id in case of success and list of errors in case of fail.
 ex code snippet:

```
def save = {
   def errors = []
    if(Employee.save(flush:true)){
      return Employee.id
    }else{
      errors.add("Can't be saved")
      return errors.
    }

   }
```

In Service class
ICalling 
  Employee.save() - .. so how to check if it is error or id that save method returns

Any suggestions around would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this - even if you can make it somewhat more usable with Groovy, it's a bad idea. In this case though, there are a few simple solutions. If you're just passing the Employee instance and saving it in the service method, you don't need to return anything:

```
void save(Employee employee) {
   employee.save(flush:true)
}
```

This is because if it's successful, the id will be set on the instance you passed in, and if not there will be one or more validation errors in the `errors` property (there's no need for you to return a generic error message when there are actually useful error messages available).

For example this would be the code you'd have in a controller calling the service:

```
def employee = new Employee(...)
fooService.save(employee)
if (employee.hasErrors()) {
   // do something with employee.errors
}
else {
   // success - use the id if you need via employee.id
}
```

If you want to pass in the data to create and save the new instance and return an Employee (this is the approach I usually take), it's similar:

```
Employee save(String name, int foo, boolean bar, ...) {
   Employee employee = new Employee(name: name, foo: foo, bar: bar, ...)
   employee.save(flush:true)
   return employee
}
```

In this second case it's important to separate the `save` call and the `return`, since if there is a validation error `save` returns `null` and you want to always return a non-null instance. So do not do this:

```
return employee.save(flush:true)
```

If you separate them you can check the errors and/or the id.

Also, make sure that you do *not* use closures in services like you have in your code (`def save = { ...`). Only methods will be transactional since the Spring transaction handling doesn't know about Groovy closures - they're just fields that Groovy calls as if they were methods, but they're not.

Comment: Burt: I got whar you are saying but I have to return custom errors and not doing validations on domain since I'm working on webservices, so can I pass List errors as part of save method.  Like in Service  def errors = [] ; service.save(id,name,no,errors)..so since errors is a list object and no need to return.

Comment: I recommend to print the errors to log from within the service. Beside of that i totally agree.

Comment: If you absolutely need to return your own errors, use a Map, or a dedicated result object. As a Map: [id:employee.id,errors:myErrors]

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Burk not to return different types, it can lead to unexpected errors. 
Another solution to the problem is using Java's exception handling mechanism. You can add a context field to the Exception which will hold the list of validation errors.After catching the exception you can extract the errors.

```
void save(Employee employee) {
    // do save
    // ...

    // on error:
    def errors = [ "terrible error nr. 5" ]
    throw new ValidationException(errors)
}


try {
    fooService.save(employee)
} catch(ValidationException e) {
    def errors = e.erorrs
    // do stuff with the errors
}
```

An additional advantage: When no validation error is expected, the try-catch block can be ommited in Groovy, which makes the code cleaner because you don't have to care about any validation error fields.